# Merge two array and result as new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array, I want combine it., but for me it not easy.

**Edited.**

I want convert this array

```
[poll_answer] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fasya
        [1] => Maulana
    )

[poll_image] => Array
    (
        [0] => 176
        [1] => 290
    )
```

to new array like this

```
[poll_data] => Array
    (
        [poll_answer] => Fasya
        [poll_image] => 176
    )

[poll_data] => Array
    (
        [poll_answer] => Maulana
        [poll_image] => 290
    )
```

Comment: Check out the `array_combine` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Now that I understand your question better I believe I came up with a concept answer which should help you head in the right direction with your array:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $array1 ); $i++ )
{
    $array['poll_data'] = array(
        'poll_answer' => $array1['poll_answer'][$i],
        'poll_image' => $array1['poll_image'][$i]
    );
    print_r($array);
}
```

In this case I am using the `array` keys and taking advantage of the numeric array you have on the second part. An example of what I am doing is `$array1['poll_answer'][0]` will output `Fasya`. With that in mind, you can reset up the array in a dynamic method and call each part of the array that you need.

Run a `for` loop and inside of the loop, inside create a new loop which is what you want. Your output should be:

```
Array
(
    [poll_data] => Array
        (
            [poll_answer] => Fasya
            [poll_image] => 176
        )

)
Array
(
    [poll_data] => Array
        (
            [poll_answer] => Maulana
            [poll_image] => 290
        )

)
```

### Update

I noticed you want the same keys, for that you actually have to use `array_merge_recursive` which will preserve your array keys in the same way. PHP Manual says:

> array_merge_recursive() merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

So the same setup, and instead of joining the arrays with `array_merge` use `array_merge_recursive`:

```
$c_array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

For more information on `array_merge_recursive` you can check our their documentation on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), there will be also some examples you can check out.

Cheers

---

You can simply use `array_merge`, as per PHP Manual documentation:

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

This is what the syntax looks like:

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

1. `$array1` is the main array
2. `array $...` is the other arrays that you want to merge with the initial array.

Now in practice, this is what it would look like:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    'poll_data' => array(
        'poll_answer' => 'Fasya',
        'poll_image' => 176
    )
);
$array2 = array(
    'poll_data' => array(
        'poll_answer' => 'Maulana',
        'poll_image' => 290
    )
);
```

Then call the `array_merge` function

```
$c_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

For more details on what the overall aspect of `array_merge` is you can always check out their documentation on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). It will explain each parameter, and it will also have some examples for your to look at.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not working :-( if you confused with my question,i edited.

Comment: Oh my bad... I think I know where you can find the answer @Opsional

Comment: @Opsional give me a minute... I am working on a script I think will work